# Bug in new close vote link

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

The close votes just changed, instead of seeing `close(3)`, you now see `close(3/5)`. That's usefull, but there is something not working correctly.

When you cast a close vote, the link changed into something like this:

[image: close vote bug]

When refreshing the page, it just shows `close(3/5)` (the expected behaviour). From that, I think I can conclude it is a bug in the jQuery script which updates this link when casting a vote.

---

Please note that we also need to change the privilege pages about close votes: ["view close votes"](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) and ["cast close and reopen votes"](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: Please check the privilege page again.

Comment: @Oded I don't see any change on SO? (even after a hard refresh)

Comment: The next newest question which was asked 40 minutes before this was for the same exact issues and it was also marked as duplicate. May I ask how did you miss it?

Comment: @WouterJ - What links do you get? I see `/review/close` and `/review/open`, as should be.

Comment: @Oded I thought I said the privilege page not the review page?

Comment: @JoshMein I think because I searched for the wrong words, this looks indeed a really stupid mistake from my side...

Comment: @WouterJ - I thought you meant the links there. And the privilege pages are _wiki_ pages - you can edit them (edit on Meta, the changes will be propagated to the rest of the network at a certain stage).

Comment: @Oded thank you, I didn't know that! (how can I change it, I don't see an 'edit' link?)

Comment: I updated the privilege pages with examples that reflect the new changes (see ["view close votes"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) and ["cast close and reopen votes"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)). Let me know if I missed anything.