# New close vote count by the closing link

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-overflow, vote-to-close

A new feature [introduced today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595/181223) is that not only a count is displayed by the `close` link, but also the total number of votes needed to complete the action (5 for closing).

First of all, there seems to be a glitch when casting a close vote:

[image: glitch screenshot]

Second of all, can someone explain to me how this is helpful? I would guess that people privileged to see these numbers already know quite well how many votes are needed to close/delete a question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171937/bug-in-new-close-vote-link

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Oh...

Comment: This is the forth or fifth duplicate today.

Comment: @Oded This could be saved for the discussion part, but... Okay.

Comment: I would expect this would be helpful if they want to move away from the straight-up 5 close votes needed to close a question. Maybe to increase the number of votes needed on a highly-voted question, or perhaps to reduce the number of votes needed on a beta site. I'm just guessing, though.

Comment: @Oded and the 3rd in the last hour. How people are missing the duplicates who knows.

Comment: @JoshMein I do. Some people just don't constantly refresh Meta, which seems the only way to know if a question has been asked. The usual search or pre-posting suggestions just don't help me on Meta.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Dont need to when the duplicates are 2 of the top 3 newest questions. How is it hard to refresh the home page before posting a question?

Comment: @JoshMein I now see one of them on the home page. Even more misterious how it didn't show up in search results when I ordered them newest first.